# Why hasn't Extremis filled the gap in Killian's brain?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3

In *Iron Man 3*, Killian shows Pepper a live feed of his brain [[1]](https://youtu.be/3SbIkzqIh_M?t=54s). He then claims to show her evidence that the human brain hasn't finished evolving--there is a clear gap present [[2]](https://youtu.be/3SbIkzqIh_M?t=1m33s), a gap which, when filled, would provide the subject with extraordinary powers and healing capabilities. The "next step in human evolution." This is what Extremis does--it allows the brain to access that missing gap and take the next step.

> Extremis enhances the user's physiology by rewriting their DNA. It harnessed bio-electricity in the body and used to **activate parts of the brain that governed repair** and recode it chemically.

Source: [[3]](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Extremis)

Clearly, at this point in the movie, Killian has already been "extremified." We see that he has a much better grasp on his powers in that he is the only character we see breathe fire [[4]](https://youtu.be/N9Hk1aFwQns) and it is hinted that his miraculous physical transformation is the result of Extremis, and not, as he claims, "5 years of physical therapy".

> After **curing himself of his disability through Maya Hansen's research of Extremis**, he conducted many illegal experiments, of which several resulted in the explosions of his test subjects.

Source: [[5]](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Aldrich_Killian)

So here is my question. If that look into his brain was truly a live feed (which we can see as the hologram responds to Pepper pinching him) [[6]](https://youtu.be/3SbIkzqIh_M?t=1m9s), why does he still have a gap in his brain? Why has it not been filled, given that he has already been on Extremis for a long time? Does the activation not actually fill in the gap? What was even the point of showing the gap if so?

I guess I'm still a little confused as to how Extremis functions. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'd presume that his gap is simply smaller than others who haven't been on the treatments - but the reason he's after funding/co-operation with Stark is to make further steps forward in the process.

Comment: Wow, good question! If I remember correctly, Killian *invites* Pepper to pinch his arm. The whole 'visualization' of Killian's brain could have been staged, with footage of another brain.

Comment: This is entirely speculation, but i would assume Killian would create that hologram in such a way as to hide his amazing power and create a fake "gap" that isn't there. He's a villain trying to hide his powers and identity after all.